# No permission to chown /mnt/hdd

Tags: fstab, chown, exfat

I don't have permission to chown the mounted directory /mnt/hdd. I am currently logged in as root. The `ls -l` output is:

```
rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 131072 Jan  1  1970 hdd
```

I am mounting it via fstab config:

```
/dev/sda1 /mnt/hdd exfat-fuse defaults 0 0
```

I am trying to assign the owner of that drive to www-data via that command:

```
root@owncloud:/mnt# chown -R www-data:www-data hdd
```

and it says I don't have permission to do that.

`mount` command output:

```
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/hdd type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: Do include the actual error message from `chown`. It may or may not be important in this particular question, but in general it's always better to include it than to not include error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/mnt/hdd` is an ExFAT filesystem, which does not actually have a concept of Unix-style file ownerships nor permissions, and so cannot store them. This is why your `chown` command is failing.

The ownerships and permissions displayed by `ls -l` are actually created on-the-fly by the `exfat-fuse` driver according to the mount options. Since the default list of mount options includes `allow_other`, the driver is currently allowing full access to all the files and directories in this filesystem to any user on the system.

You could use the `id www-data` command to display the user and group ID numbers of the `www-data` user. If the `www-data` has UID of 33 and primary GID of also 33, you could change your `/etc/fstab` line to:

```
/dev/sda1 /mnt/hdd exfat-fuse default_permissions,allow_root,uid=33,gid=33,nosuid,nodev,relatime,blksize=4096 0 0
```

Then unmount & re-mount the filesystem:

```
umount /mnt/hdd
mount /mnt/hdd
```

Now all the file and directory ownerships and permissions in the `/mnt/hdd` filesystem should have changed.

Note that this kind of Unix ownership and permission emulation for filesystems that don't have the capability to store Unix-style ownership/permission information is restricted to what you can specify with mount options: usually, it means that all the files and all the directories in that filesystem will have a single, fixed set of ownership/permission settings and they cannot be changed with `chown`/`chmod` commands at all. If this is too inflexible for you, I'm afraid the only option would be to use another filesystem type.

It this is a temporary setup, using an ExFAT filesystem to hold web server data (as indicated by the username `www-data`) might be fine. But if this is supposed to be a permanent setup, you should seriously consider reformatting `/dev/sda1` to another filesystem type that allows native Unix-style file ownerships and permissions before starting to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `/etc/fstab` entry to:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/maria/Lexfat exfat defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/923691/ownership-permission-problem-with-automounting-exfat-drive